# Converter boolToVisibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I would learn to use converter on Wpf(xaml).

```
<Window x:Class="TextExpanderGriglia.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextExpanderGriglia"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="CIAO" Width="50" Height="50" Visibility="{Binding vButton,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"> </Button>
    <Button Content="Cambia" Width="50" Height="50"  Margin="56,134,411,135" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

This is my Xaml code.
Stupid example to start, I have 2 button and on button "Cambia" I set boolean value vButton = !vButton, but also if vButton is false the first button doesn't hide.
What is missing in my code?

This is my converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool vButton;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool VButton
    {
        get
        {
            return vButton;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != vButton)
            {
                this.vButton = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("VButton");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        vButton = !vButton;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your ViewModel code as well?

Comment: did you bind the `DataContext`?

Comment: Where (namespace) does your BoolToVisibilityConverter reside?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your `BoolToVisibilityConverter`, does it ever get hit? Because if not it means your binding is very likely incorrect.

Comment: `vButton` must be a public property of the object in the DataContext of your Window, and the object's class must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify about a changed value of the property. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom added

Comment: @LeiYang no, where I must bind it?

Comment: @mindOfAi Namespace is TextExpanderGriglia

Comment: @user2657943 no.. I know it is wrong, but I don't know why

Comment: You added a screenshot from the view but no viewmodel code, did you?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom added

Answer (score 1):

The converter looks fine.

Most likely scenario here is that the property you are binding to is not raising change notifications. For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isButtonVisible;

    public bool vButton
    {
        get { return _isButtonVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isButtonVisible)
                return;
            _isButtonVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: and on Xaml what change?

Comment: Are you actually binding the DataContext of this control to your viewmodel anywhere?

Comment: If it's not working, put breakpoints in the property getter, setter and in your converter. Most likely something is not being hit, which will tell you what you're missing.

Comment: @LordWilmore how ? where?

Comment: @DrewNoakes never get it.. But I don't know why

Comment: If you're not hitting anything then you aren't setting your `DataContext`.

Comment: And how can I set it? @DrewNoakes

Comment: myView.DataContext = myViewModel.  Go and read a tutorial on WPF data binding.

Answer (score 0):

To set DataContext

In your constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

In MVVM pattern, you should define the ViewModel separately from your Windows.
For ex. in your case:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool vButton;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool VButton
    {
        get
        {
            return vButton;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != vButton)
            {
                this.vButton = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("VButton");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```